# How to make Java application memory allocated editable?

Tags: java, memory, allocation

I have seen a Java application that allows its users to manually edit the application memory allocated. Here is its screenshot:

[image]

Does someone know how I can do a similar thing to my application?

Comment: It does not edit the "allocated memory" but defines a argument to the jvm which is passed on starting minecraft

Comment: Can you say what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not Minecraft which allocates memory for itself. MagicLauncher is a seperate program that calls `java` with the correct parameters to start minecraft.jar.

To allocate memory for Java, you can use for example `java -jar -Xmx512 program.jar` to give program.jar 512 megabytes of memory.

Comment: Thanks .. I guess that's what i will do :)